# C# Keep Changes Made in Method Out of Scope

Tags: c#

Still virtually a beginner with C# programming - help with what is probably an elementary problem very much appreciated.

I have a number of objects in an application that implement a common interface.  I want to create a method that will accept any collection of objects that implement that interface, perform an operation on those objects, with the original collection having been transformed.

The behaviour I am seeing is that the objects are manipulated in the scope of the method external to the calling code, but not where and after the call.  I am unable to figure out how to solve this.

Here is a simplified version of the code I've been testing this with.

The interface as follows:

```
public interface IDated
{
    DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

An example of an object implementing that interface:

```
public class MyObject : IDated
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

The method that changes the objects:

```
public class Operator
{
    public void Operate(IEnumerable<IDated> objects)
    {
        objects = from o in objects where o.Date.HasValue select o;
    }
}
```

The calling code, where at the end no change has occurred:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var one = new MyObject("One", null);
        var two = new MyObject("Two", DateTime.Parse("30-06-06"));

        var list = new List<MyObject>();
        list.Add(one);
        list.Add(two);

        new Operator().Operate(list);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Objects in list = {0}\r\nOperation Succeeded: {1}", list.Count.ToString(), (list.Count == 1).ToString()));
    }
```

The output is "2" and "False".  Googling this problem, I've had a try at passing the collection in as "ref" argument, as in:

```
public void Operate(ref IEnumerable<IDated> objects)
    {
        objects = from o in objects where o.Date.HasValue select o;
    }
```

And:

```
new Operator().Operate(ref list);
```

However the last bit of code has a beautiful vibrant red underline, and it reckons the argument is invalid.  I am unable to see why?

Again, any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Tim.

Comment: Your `Operate` function should actually *return* your new list. That is the only way to get the new list back to your calling function.

Comment: So then you have a List<IDated>, but you need a List<MyObject>.  Therefore, how do you cast this on output? I've tried this, but unable to get the casting...

Comment: You can call Cast<MyObject>() on the IEnumerable<IDated> if you have System.Linq in your using stataments

Comment: @Gabe - That is not true, you can also specify a ref or out parameter or manipulate the input list (if of a collection type)

Comment: i thought your question was more theoretical.  why don't the changes to the reference type IList<MyObject> persist outside the scope of the method being called.

Comment: @Polity: You're right that there are other ways are *possible*, but I've never seen a situation where that's really what you'd want. Using `ref` or `out` parameters means that you have to pass in a variable of type `IEnumerable<Dated>` so you can't chain the methods.

Comment: @Gabe: `ref` or `out` yes, I haven't seen a case where that is what you'd actually want.  Passing in a collection type and modifying it within the function isn't unreasonable, though, but it totally depends on how your code is factored.  With this hypothetical and anemic example, it doesn't make any sense.  But it does in some real code that could still be considered well-factored.  For example code to prune certain values from a collection or tree (which has child collections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Operate` function should actually *return* your new list. That is the only way to get the new list back to your calling function.

Note that this means you can't say:

```
var list = new List<MyObject>();
list = new Operator().Operate(list);
```

You either need to say this:

```
var list = new List<MyObject>();
list.Add(one);
list.Add(two);
var output = new Operator().Operate(list);
```

or this:

```
IEnumerable<IDated> list = new List<MyObject> { one, two };
list = new Operator().Operate(list);
```

Comment: the only way? I am not sure about that.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: The only way *worth considering*.

Comment: Thanks, Gabe - this was the first thought I had.  However, as mentioned in the comments above, casting was a problem.  However, TheEvilPenguin's comment above does indeed solve that problem, making this an attractive solution.

Comment: the evilpenguin's comment - hahahhahaha

Answer (score 1):

So you will get the expected results if you put execute your writeline statement in the Operator.Operate method.  I think the implicit cast from IList<MyObject> to IEnumerable<IDated> creates a temporary variable that is only in scope for the duration of the method call.

Changing the code to this (using terse syntax)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var one = new MyObject("One", null);
            var two = new MyObject("Two", DateTime.Parse("06-30-06"));

            var list = new List<IDated> {one, two};

            new Operator().Operate(ref list);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Objects in list = {0}\r\nOperation Succeeded: {1}", list.Count.ToString(), (list.Count == 1).ToString()));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

and

```
public class Operator
{
    public void Operate(ref List<IDated> objects)
    {
        objects = objects.Where(o => o.Date.HasValue).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Objects in list = {0}\r\nOperation Succeeded: {1}", objects.Count(), objects.Count() == 1));
    }
}
```

you get the expected results.  If you don't decorate the arguments with the `ref` keyword, the list loses it's changes as the method goes out of scope.  I'm not sure why as these are all reference types, so I thought we'd see the changes in the main program if there was no casting involved.

Comment: hm, if you remove ref from your Operate signatare assignment will not affect List outside of-course. And reference type effect can be seen when we call Remove() or Clear() on list and modify the list of origin, since its not a valuetype we got an actual list and not a copy thus changes we make inside method are affecting outside list.

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method that uses yield return instead (of course, then you'll be returning an enumeration instead of modifying the enumeration itself, which is what you should be doing anyways when working with enumerations).

```
public static class IDatedExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> HasDate(IEnumerable<T> objects)
        where T : IDated
    {
        foreach (var obj in objects)
        {
            if ((obj != null) && (obj.Date.HasValue))
                yield return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void Foo()
{
    var list = new List<MyObject>();
    list.Add(one);
    list.Add(two);

    foreach (var obj in list.HasDate())
    {
        //You should really have this be culture aware since you're working
        //with DateTime...
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            "{0}: {1}", obj.Name, obj.Date.Value));
    }
}

public void Foo2()
{
    var list = new List<MyObject>();
    list.Add(one);
    list.Add(two);

    //Use LINQs ToList() to get a new List<T>
    var newList = list.HasDate().ToList();

    ...
}
```

---

Oh, and side note:

`Console.WriteLine(string format, params Object[] args)` already formats the string for you, String.Format within it is unnecessary unless you plan on supplying the IFormatProvider as well (which in your case you should, but you didn't)...

I should also mention that although this isn't the same as what is being asked, I figured I'd throw this answer out there because if you're new to C#, you might as well start off on the right foot. Don't modify collections you are iterating over. Use enumerations to `yield` return objects from your enumeration.

Comment: Why go through all the trouble of yielding instances when you can simply do your filtering with Linq and return the query?

Comment: His example used `IDated` ... personally, I've only ever implemented one additional LINQ method, which was a Page method, which worked similar to the Skip/Take methods except that if you supplied an out of bounds page it would return the first page/last page, so you could do... `foreach (var item in items.Paginate(10, Int32.MaxValue)) { ... }`. Still, I think it's good for the OP to understand how to use extension methods and enumerations properly, hence why I answered.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using Extension Methods for building a pipeline. Your code would then be something like:

```
public static DatedSetExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IDated> WhereHasDate(this IEnumerable<IDated> input)
    {
        return input.Where(x => x.Date.HasValue);
    }
}

...

list = list.WhereHasDate();
```

Note though that IEnumerable is very different from a list. IEnumerable only knows how to traverse a certain collection. It doesn't actually store it or knows how to manipulate it.

If you want your original code to operate on the given collection, you should provide it with the right type, namely: a collection, like:

```
    public void FilterByHasDate(this Collection<IDated> input)
    {
        var itemsToRemove = input.Where(x => x.Date.HasValue).ToArray();
        foreach (var itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
        {
            input.Remove(itemToRemove);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** I assume now you want your extension method to return the original type of the elements within the input collection. You can easily manage this with generics and type constraints like:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar : Foo {}

static class FooExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereSomething<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input) where T: Foo
    {
        return input;
    }
}

....

List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();
IEnumerable<Bar> filteredBars = bars.WhereSomething();
```

Here we have a operator working over a Foo collection but still returning a bar collection just like what we passed into it. Thanks to generics

Comment: Your `FilterByHasDate` method won't work. For one thing, you generally can't modify a collection while you're enumerating it. Another problem is that any arbitrary `ICollection<T>` may be read-only. It will always work if it's a `List<T>`, but at that point you could just call `List.RemoveAll()`.

Comment: @Gabe - thanks for the tip. I ment to move the setToRemove to memory but forgot to add that in the sample code. will do that now. Your second statement is wrong though. ICollection<T> by contract is there to manipulate a collection. You're probably confused with the non-generic ICollection which indeed can't be modified.

Comment: I've tried this out, and it works a treat (the edited solution with generics).  To my mind, it is a very nice solution to the problem.  However, it goes a bit beyond what I was going for, so I've marked Gabe's the answer, since I've used it (albeit with a Cast<> added to the mix).  Thanks, mate.

Comment: Go ahead and try it if you don't believe me. Create an array of `MyObject` instances where some have dates and some don't, and pass it to `FilterByHasDate`. You'll get an exception in the call to `Remove`.

Comment: @Gabe - What are you talking about? I forgot to materialize the itemsToDelete query, and as i indicated in my last comment, i would update the code, which i did. This works perfectly fine. You can remove items in a foreach as long as the underlying collection Source isn't the same collection source as the one your enumerating over.

Comment: What I mean is that `MyObject[]` implements `ICollection<MyObject>`, but you can't change the size of an array so the `Remove` method throws an exception. Go ahead and execute `FilterByHasDate(new MyObject[] { new MyObject { Date = null }, new MyObject { Date = DateTime.Now } });` if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Gabe - Ahh, that is correct but that is an implementation detail. I have no idea why MS decided to do this but that doesn't matter. Check MSDN. the generic version of ICollection is there precicely for the reason of manipulating a collection. So whenever you want to keep your code abstract. which makes it perfectly valid to use for gaining abstraction. Hell, what if the user passes in a readonly list? It's up to the user not to provide a ReadOnly collection in a manipulative operation.

Comment: @Gabe - If you have safari books online, i recommend reading http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9780735640467/arrays/all_arrays_implicitly_implement_ienumera for more information why an array implements ICollection and IList

Answer (score 0):

If you focus on finding a solution using operator defined as:

```
public void Operate(IEnumerable<IDated> objects)
```

you clearly won't find one because method isn't returning anything, and IEnumerable argument cannot be modified from inside method to cause anyone outside notice its effect. (without some smart cast to `List<T>` inside method and calling `Clear()` anyway)

If you want to actually modify input argument you can have it

```
public void Operate(List<IDated> objects)
```

Now inside operate you can call `objects.Remove()` for matching objects.

And after calling this void method actual list will become modified.

Your approach with passing `List<T>` as `ref IEnumerable<T>` is doomed when you try to assign a `List<T>` variable to `IEnumerable<T>` inside your method, just pass it as `ref List<T>` inside if you actually like ref approach (which I don't) OR assign it to `List<T>` by calling `.ToList()` on resulting IEnumerable

Comment: That's very insightful, thank you.  Question: Any reason why my compiler reckons the List<MyObject> is an invalid argument for Operation(List<IDated> objects), but valid for Operation(List<MyObject> objects)?

Comment: @nulliusinverba - You're hitting an issue with covariance. Basically it goes like this: even though `MyObject` "inherits" from `IDated`, `List<MyObject>` does NOT inherit from `List<IDated>` - so you can't make this assignment.

Comment: Generics generally don't support covariance which will be required for your line to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is fine, but these lines won't work:

```
public class Operator
{
    public void Operate(IEnumerable<IDated> objects)
    {
        objects = from o in objects where o.Date.HasValue select o;
    }
}
```

There are some problems with this approach:

- Assigning to a normal non-ref method parameter doesn't change anything outside the function
- `IEnumerable` is designed for reading data, not (directly) modifying it

**Method parameters are like additional temporary variables**

Here is a sample describing why re-assigning `objects` won't work.  It is very similar to the code you already have here:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void Something()
    {
        List<int> values = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        IEnumerable<int> valuesParam = values;
        valuesParam = values.Where(i => i < 3);

        // Will print 1 through 5, not 1 through 2...
        foreach(int value in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when you call a method, you're making *another* variable that refers to your initial variable.  Then when you re-assign to it, you're just reassigning to that temporary variable.  When that temporary variable goes away, so do your changes.

**IEnumerable is used for read-only access**

You'll notice that `IEnumerable` isn't something you can modify.  You can't `Add` or `Remove` from an `IEnumerable`.  So you'd have to do some sort of assignment to get your `Operate` method to work.

**Using `ref`**

You tried to solve this using `ref`, but that won't work, because the value you are passing in is a `List<IDated>`, not an `IEnumerable<IDated>`.  The types basically have to match.

You could fix this, but `ref` is a bit more painful to use in general, so I wouldn't recommend it...

**Using a return value**

You could instead solve this by re-assigning the *original* value of the list, by passing back your filtered list as a return value.  Since you take an `IEnumerable<IDated>`, I recommend you return one too, and use the `ToList()` method on the result to turn it back into the same type as the original list.

```
list = new Operator()
    .Operate(list)
    .ToList(); // Note: Important!

// ...

public IEnumerable<IDated> Operate(IEnumerable<IDated> objects)
{
    return objects.Where(o => o.Date.HasValue);
}
```